# Pythonのtry,exceptで変数が更新されない

Tags: python, python3

```
inin = input().rstrip().split(' ')
sakana, poi, Durability = int(inin[0]), int(inin[1]), int(inin[2])

d = Durability
count = 0

def check(d, w, count, poi):
    if d > w:
        count += 1
        d = d - w
    else:
        poi -= 1
        if poi > 0:
            d = Durability
        check(d, w, count, poi)

for _ in range(sakana):
    w = int(input())

    try:
        check(d, w, count, poi)
    except RecursionError:
        break

print(count)
```

例えばcountが0のまま変動しません、なぜでしょう？
解決策が全くわかりません。独学なので汚いコードかもしれませんすいません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

try, except は無関係で、`count = 0`および`print(count)`の`count`と、`def check(d, w, count, poi):`の中の`count += 1`の`count`が別の物を指しているからです。

`count += 1`の結果は1つの`def check(d, w, count, poi):`の呼び出し中だけで有効であり、その外側の`count`や次の呼び出しの`count`には影響を与えません。

同じ`count`を使うためには、`def check(d, w, count, poi):`からパラメータとしての`count,`は削除して、その処理の先頭で`if d > w:`の前に、`global count`を挿入しましょう。

以下の様になるでしょう。

```
inin = input().rstrip().split(' ')
sakana, poi, Durability = int(inin[0]), int(inin[1]), int(inin[2])

d = Durability
count = 0

def check(d, w, poi):   # パラメータ削除
    global count        # global変数を使う

    if d > w:
        count += 1
        d = d - w
    else:
        poi -= 1
        if poi > 0:
            d = Durability
        check(d, w, poi)    # パラメータ削除

for _ in range(sakana):
    w = int(input())

    try:
        check(d, w, poi)    # パラメータ削除
    except RecursionError:
        break

print(count)
```

その他の変数についても、もし必要があれば、対処を考えてください。

Comment: そういったルールがあるのですね、ありがとうございました。